# Сколько одновременных соединений выдерживает WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, digitalocean

На небольшом инстансе на digitalocean (1 CPU, 1 Gb RAM, Ubuntu 14) установлен WordPress без каких-либо плагинов.

Я заметил что MySQL на нем падает после 10 одновременных соединений. Немного изменив настройки MySQL удалось добиться работы не более примерно 20 одновременных запросов.

Вопросы - это нормально? Какую вообще нагрузку должен выдерживать WordPress и MySQL? Как вообще живут высоконагруженные WordPress сайты? Что надо изменить чтобы повысить нагрузку (кроме очевидного повышения мощности инстанса)? Как можно автоматически поднимать MySQL после падения?

Кэширование страниц - не вариант, предполагается что будут работать залогиненные пользователи с разным контентом.

Тестирование я делал с помощью Apache Jmeter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При правильной настройке сервера - до 10,000 соединений в секунду. Почитайте мою статью https://kagg.eu/10000-clients-second-wordpress/ с результатами нагрузочных тестов.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!

Comment: Apache сразу выкидывайте, кстати.